# The Supreme Lord Is Equal to Everyone but he became partial for Indra

Tags: vishnu, gods

The supreme Personality of Godhead Lord Vishnu is equal to everyone.How he became partial like a common man for Indra and killing Indra's enemies. How can a person be equal to everyone be partial to someone at some instances?

Answer (score 2):

> Srimad Bagavatham Canto 7.1 states that  in response to a question by
> Mahārāja Parīkṣit, Śukadeva Gosvāmī gives his conclusions concerning
> how the Supreme Personality of Godhead, although the Supersoul, friend
> and protector of everyone, killed the Daityas, the demons, for the
> sake of Indra, the King of heaven.
>
> In his statements, he totally  refutes the arguments of people in general who accuse the Supreme Lord  of partiality. Śukadeva Gosvāmī proves that because the body of the  conditioned soul is infected by the three qualities of nature,
> dualities arise such as enmity and friendship, attachment and
> detachment. For the Supreme Personality of Godhead, however, there are
> no such dualities. Even eternal time cannot control the activities of
> the Lord. Eternal time is created by the Lord, and it acts under His
> control.
>
> The Supreme Personality of Godhead, therefore, is always
> transcendental to the influence of the modes of nature, māyā, the
> Lord’s external energy, which acts in creation and annihilation. Thus
> all the demons killed by the Supreme Lord attain salvation
> immediately.
>
> The second question raised by Parīkṣit Mahārāja concerns
> how Sisupala, although inimical toward Kṛishna from his very childhood
> and always blaspheming Kṛishna, attained salvation in oneness when Kṛishna
> killed him. Sukadeva Gosvamī explains that because of their offenses
> at the feet of devotees, two attendants of the Lord in Vaikuṇṭha named
> Jaya and Vijaya became Hiraṇyakaśipu and Hiraṇyākṣa in Satya-yuga,
> Rāvaṇa and Kumbhakarṇa in the next yuga, Treta-yuga, and Sisupala and
> Dantavakra at the end of Dvapara-yuga.
>
> Because of their fruitive acts,Jaya and Vijaya agreed to become the Lord’s enemies, and when killed  in that mentality, they attained salvation in oneness. Thus even if  one thinks of the Supreme Personality of Godhead in envy, he attains  salvation. What then is to be said of devotees who always engage in  the Lord’s service with love and faith?

Answer (score 2):

> **The supreme Personality of Godhead Lord Vishnu is equal to everyone.How he became partial**

**No** , it is not true Lord Vishnu  **was never partial to Indra** , but because Indra became intoxicated with opulence  imagining himself the supreme controller. Lord Vishnu in order to teach him a lesson performed some actions.

Lord Vishnu took the side of Indra and Killed the two sons of Diti – Hiranyakshapu and Hiranyaksha. as described in this chapter of [**Shreemad Bhagvat Purana.**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/18)

Shree Shuka Said –

> हतपुत्रा दिति: शक्रपार्षाणिग्राहेण विष्णुना |
>  मन्युना शोकदीप्तेन
>   ज्वलन्ति पर्यचिन्तयत् ||23||
>
> hata-putrā ditiḥ śakra-pārṣṇi-grāheṇa viṣṇunā 
>  manyunā
>   śoka-dīptena jvalantī paryacintayat
>
> Śrī Śukadeva Gosvāmī said: **Just to help Indra, Lord Viṣṇu killed the
>   two brothers Hiraṇyākṣa and Hiraṇyakaśipu.** Because of their being
>   killed, their mother, Diti, overwhelmed with lamentation and anger,
>   contemplated as follows. [**SB 6.18.23**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/18/23)

---

When Indra understood that his sacrifice had been put aside, he became furious with Nanda and the other cowherd men, who were accepting Krishna as their Lord. Angry Indra sent forth the clouds of universal destruction, known as Sāṁvartaka and Imagining himself the supreme controller,

> गणं सांवर्तकं नामा मेघानां चान्तकारिणाम् |
>  इन्द्र: प्राचोद्यत
>   कृध्दो वाक्यं चाहेशमान्युत ||2||
>
> gaṇaṁ sāṁvartakaṁ nāma meghānāṁ cānta-kārīṇām indraḥ pracodayat
>   kruddho vākyaṁ cāheśa-māny uta
>
> Angry Indra sent forth the clouds of universal destruction, known as
>   Sāṁvartaka. Imagining himself the supreme controller, he spoke as
>   follows.[SB 10.25.2](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/25/2)

**See what supreme Lord Says to Indra –**

> मया तेsकारि मघवन् मखभङ्गोsनुगृह्यता |
>  मदनुस्मृतये नित्यं
>   मत्तस्येन्द्रश्रिया भृशम ||15||
>
> mayā te ’kāri maghavan makha-bhaṅgo ’nugṛhṇatā mad-anusmṛtaye nityaṁ
>   mattasyendra-śriyā bhṛśam
>
> The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: My dear Indra, it was out of
>   mercy that I stopped the sacrifice meant for you. **You were greatly
>   intoxicated by your opulence as King of heaven, and I wanted you to
>   always remember Me.**[**SB 10.27.15**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/27/15)